# Betfair API, BETTING_RESTRICTED_LOCATION when logging in from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, betfair

I am trying to use Python / Google App Engine to log into the Betfair API.

When I try to log in using the API on GAE, I get a BETTING_RESTRICTED_LOCATION error.

When I run the script locally (from the UK) it works fine.

So it appears that Betfair is blocking my script as it is running from a US based IP address. This is because US citizens can't use Betfair. But I am a UK based UK Citizen, so the rule does not apply to me.

How can I get round this login problem?

Comment: This isn't really a code question, but I'd try tunneling using something like Tor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easily actually.

If you fill in [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1W7LsnYRj0eBAzEQlDtFbsVuIZ0nFU2TaP7cZiaY4Z0Q/viewform?formkey=dDllb3FHLS1IdXVIcjVKR3FScklka1E6MQ), you can specify where your App will be hosted and ran, so you can limit it to EU and then Betfair should work.

Comment: Thanks! From my own googling I only found that it was for Premier, not freebie accounts.

Comment: I also found another solution... Using the Keepalive Betfair API call, I can keep a session token alive, which is a better solution for me as it means I don't need to store user date inside my script. However, I will use your form as having a European server should reduce my latency